# scss parse error in p :not(table p)

Tags: css, sass

I used scss and I've got a css parse error in this line

```
p :not(table p) {
   color: red !important;
}
```

> Unexcepted token LBrace Found

Can anyone please point out what mistake in this scss.

Comment: Tried with the online compiler @ http://www.sassmeister.com/ and no errors.

Comment: The selector itself is impossible though.

Comment: Note `table p` is not a simple selector. Selectors level 3 only allows simple selectors in `:not()`. Selectors level 4 may remove this restriction in the future.

Comment: Don't ask multiple issues in the same question. Ask a new question instead.

Comment: @Oriol ok I will ask it as seperate question